# KDB+: How to retrieve the rows immediately before and after a given row that conform to a specific logic?

Tags: kdb

Given the following table

```
time    kind    counter    key1    value
----------------------------------------
1       1       1          1       1
2       0       1          1       2
3       0       1          2       3
5       0       1          1       4
5       1       2          2       5
6       0       2          3       6
7       0       2          2       7
8       1       3          3       8
9       1       4          3       9
```

How would one select the value in the first row
immediately after and immediately before each
row of kind 1 ordered by time where the key1
value is the same in both instances .i.e:

```
time      value       prevvalue     nextvalue
---------------------------------------------
1         1           0n            2
5         5           3             7
8         8           6             0n
9         9           6             0n
```

Here are some of the things I have tried, though
to be honest I have no idea how to canonically achieve
something like this in q whereby the prior value has a
variable offset to the current row?

```
select 
     prev[value],
     next[value],
     by key1 where kind<>1

 
     update 0N^prevval,0N^nextval from update prevval:prev value1,nextval:next value1 by key1 from table
```

Some advice or a pointer on how to achieve this would be great!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use the following code to return a table meeting your requirements. If this is correct, the sample table you have provided is incorrect, otherwise I have misunderstood the question.

```
q)table:([] time:1 2 3 5 5 6 7 8 9;kind:1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1;counter:1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 4;key1:1 1 2 1 2 3 2 3 3;value1:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)  

q)tab2:update 0N^prevval,0N^nextval from update prevval:prev value1,nextval:next value1 by key1 from table

q)tab3:select from tab2 where kind=1
  time value1 prevval nextval
  ---------------------------
   1    1              2
   5    5      3       7
   8    8      6       9
   9    9      8
```

The update statement in tab2:

```
  update 0N^prevval,0N^nextval from update prevval:prev value1,nextval:next value1 by key1 from table
```

is simply adding 2 columns onto the original table with the previous and next values for each row. `0^` is filling the empty fields with nulls.

The select statement in tab3:

```
tab3:select from tab2 where kind=1
```

is filtering tab2 for rows where kind=1.

The final select statement:

```
select time,value1,prevval,nextval from tab3
```

is selecting the rows you want to be returned in the final result.

Hope this answers your question.

Thanks,
Caitlin

Comment: Hey Caitlin, Thanks for taking the time and effort to give your input, it is very much appreciated. It would seem trivial to solve with a solution such as the one you have provided however it doesn't account for the conditional that stipulates that the previous/next row cannot be of kind=1